# Festlegung der Grenze, die vorgenommen wurden

Tags: dative

> Eine weitere wichtige Person für die Geschichte Afghanistans war Abdur
> Rahmann Khan. Er war von 1880 bis 1901 Emir von Afghanistan. Während
> er über Afghanistan herrschte, kam es zur Festlegung **der Grenze**, die
> er als Staatsoberhaupt nicht selbst vornahm, sondern die von
> Großbritannien und Russland vorgenommen **wurden**.

Why does *der Grenze*, i.e. "of the border", get *wurden*, i.e. the plural of "became"?

Source: https://www.kinderweltreise.de/kontinente/asien/afghanistan/daten-fakten/geschichte-politik/

Answer (score 7):

That's indeed a mistake. Since the sentence is in the passive voice, a simplified version reads

> Die Festlegung wurde vorgenommen

since *Festlegung* is in the singular.

The author probably got confused, because it was two states who carried it out. It would need the plural if the sentence was in the active voice, i.e.

> Großbritannien und Russland nahmen die Festlegung vor.